# I don't have "additional drivers" on my ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I searched for it in the dash but found nothing, I really need it
I got ubuntu 12.04 on virtualbox on windows7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think you need it for. If it detects you have devices that it can install additional drivers for, it will prompt you.

Anyway, if you want to manually launch it, you can run `jockey-gtk`.

---

In the context of VirtualBox, you shouldn't use the Additional Drivers dialogue anyway. You should be using the [Guest Additions framework](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).